# Where can I find Xamarin Test Recorder in trial version of Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise addition?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I have a trial version Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise addition. I am using Windows 10 professional. 
I successfully installed Xamarin Test Recorder (Xamarin.TestRecorder.VSIX.2015.vsix).
However, I cannot see Xamarin Test Recorder in trial version Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise addition. 
I need to start running Test Recording for my Xamarin UI Test project.

Would it be correct to say that rial version Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise addition is enough to allow successfully install Xamarin Test Recorder but it is not enough for using Xamarin Test recorder - a subscription for Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise addition is required?

Regards
travis16

Comment: XTR is a standalone app.  It is not directly integrated in VS

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Test Recorder is not part of any Visual Studio version. It requires an extra download at:

[Test Recorder Preview](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/testrecorder/)

[Test Recorder at VS MarketPlace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=XamarinInc.XamarinTestRecorder2015)

Comment: And, most importantly, the Xamarin Test Recorder is a discontinued product.

Comment: Do you have a source for that statement?

Comment: Yes, see https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=XamarinInc.XamarinTestRecorder2015